# General error during class generation: Method too large: WorkflowScript.___cps___1

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Recently we have updated our jenkins jversion 2.107.3 to 2.332.3.
We are facing one issue below

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method too large: WorkflowScript.___cps___1 ()Lcom/cloudbees/groovy/cps/impl/CpsFunction;

groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodTooLargeException: Method too large: WorkflowScript.___cps___1 ()Lcom/cloudbees/groovy/cps/impl/CpsFunction;
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodWriter.computeMethodInfoSize(MethodWriter.java:2087)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:447)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:850)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1087)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:513)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:513)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Our pipeline code is not starting.

Comment: too much code in one place. make smaller functions, use shared library, ...

Comment: Hi Daggett..
Appreciate you help. We are using shared libraries. And same piece of code and work flow was working in jenkins 2.107.3 version but after updating it to 2.332.3 Its started showing the above error.

Comment: @daggett Can you please help more.

Comment: look for the largest groovy files you have in your jenkins. what are the top 5 sizes? try to simplify them for test purpose - just replace code with `echo "test"`. it flow is working now - think how to split largest files by smaller functions.

Comment: We have only one jenkins file intact with the Shared library and It is working fine with the jenkins version 2.107.3 but failing for version 2.332.3

Comment: @daggett Can you please help me to fix the jenkinsfile.